# The complexities of coin-flipping

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

A fair coin is flipped $M$ times; heads comes up $h$ times and tails, $M-h$ times.

Question: If we flip the coin $N$ more times, what is the probability $P$ that at some point during those $N$ flips the total number of heads (i.e. including $h$) is equal to the total number of tails?

Examples:

(1) $M=10$, $h=10$, $N=9$.  Here $P=0$.  Even if all the $N$ flips came up tails, at no point could the total heads and total tails counts be equal.

(2) $M=10$, $h=10$, $N=10$.  Here $P=0.5^{10}$.  The only way this will work is if you get ten tails in a row during the $N$ flips.

(3) $M=10$, $h=5$, $N=2$.  Here $P=0.5$, the probability of getting the same result two flips in a row.

But what about a case with a large $N$?  That would provide many opportunities to get a match along the way.

What is the general probabilistic formula $P$ as a function of $M$, $h$, and $N$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isnt a full answer but here's what I see:

Let $h_1$ be the number of heads after the first M throws. Let $H_t$ be the number of heads thrown after t tosses of the next N tosses, $t\leq N$. We can specify a discrete stochastic process, $Y_t=h_1+H_t$. This process is a martingale, as $E[Y_{n+1}|Y_n] = E[h_1+H_t+2Bernoulli(.5)-1]=h_1+H_t$. We can define a stopping time, $\tau_k= \inf\{t\leq (k\wedge N):Y_t-\frac{M+t}{2}=0\}$. Perhaps you can use optional stopping theorem to get a solution.